# ROW FORMAT Serde in hive

Tags: hive, hadoop-streaming

I am using hadoop 2.0.4 and working in twitter sentiment analysis. I have used flume to ingest data but now the twitter data must be stored in hive table.

I have created a table but ROW FORMAT SERDE is giving error

> 'Unable to validate'

Kindly tell me how to proceed.

Comment: Can you paste the Hive table creation sentence, please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom SerDe?

Please refer to the below information provided in [Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable) of hive

> You can create tables with a custom SerDe or using a native SerDe. A
> native SerDe is used if ROW FORMAT is not specified or ROW FORMAT
> DELIMITED is specified.

Hope the information is useful.

Comment: Sir but the twitter format is of JSON type.For that how to deal with twitter json format .how to store it??

Comment: Please refer to the link that discusses about [Serde for processing JSON data](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-a-serde-in-apache-hive/).    Hope this information will be of use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this jar

```
hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

After adding the jar you can create an external hive table containing the tweet_id and the tweet_text which refers to the tweets directory for performing sentiment analysis like this.

```
create external table load_tweets(id BIGINT,text STRING) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe' LOCATION '/user/flume/tweets'
```

You can refer to the below link for performing sentiment analysis using hive.

https://acadgild.com/blog/sentiment-analysis-on-tweets-with-apache-hive-using-afinn-dictionary/

Answer (score 0):

Check weather you have added  hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in your hive directory under lib folder. Your hive directory path will be the one which you have mentioned in your .bashrc file.